# How to remove extra space in outputText value in visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

How to remove extra space in outputText value in visualforce page?



in accountname i am getting value "test  account".i am getting two spaces.i need to put only one space remove second space.can anybody help me on this.....

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it cannot be done in visualforce's native function. Unless you use CSS or JavaScript.

But if you use a controller, it can be done in apex with [normalizeSpace()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_normalizeSpace)

Example from documentation:

```
String s1 = 
    'Salesforce \t     force.com';
String s2 = 
    s1.normalizeSpace();
System.assertEquals(
   'Salesforce force.com', s2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBSTITUTE function to replace 2 spaces with 1 space.

So should be like this.

```
<apex:outputTex value="{!SUBSTITUTE(Your_Variable, '  ', ' ')}">
```

Comment: @user You can use this : <apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(account.name,"   "," ")}"/>

Comment: @rajan for two spaces its working. If ten spaces comes between the name how to remove.

Comment: @rajan i need dynamically.

Comment: @Eric before Rajan had given same answer only.its working but in the name getting three spaces how to put one space.i need dynamically.

Comment: I did nothing but format the answer to show what they did not format properly

Answer (score 0):

Dont Worry about It, you can use "white-space: pre" to preserve white space.

I think This May Work.

style="white-space: pre"

```
<apex:outputText value="{!var1}" style="white-space: pre"/>
```